# MAGENTO : Add image field in custom module

Tags: magento, module, image

I'm creating a module and i want to add a picture in the edit page (back office), i do this :

```
$fieldset->addField('photo', 'image', array(
'label'     => "image",
'required'  => false,
'name'      => 'image',
));
```

the input is present in the page but in my controller i don't have any information about this picture, does someone can tell me how i can do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer the image upload article

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/how_to_create_pdf_upload_in_backend_for_own_module